# Is it possible to add the same comment to multiple issues in bulk using Jira API?

Tags: jira-rest-api

I'm trying to add the same comment to multiple different Jira issues using the API with cURL.

I'm currently at:

```
curl -u username:pw -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"ids": ["KEY1", "KEY2"], "body": "My comment"}' https://my.jira.domain/jira/rest/api/2/issue/bulk/comment
```

But that returns an error.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such endpoint *'https://(domain)/jira/rest/api/2/issue/bulk/comment'*, hence the error. Also, as described in the REST API documentation, the [Create Issues endpoint](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/9.8.0/#api/2/issue-createIssues) is for bulk CREATING issues.

There is no endpoint to bulk UPDATE issues. Google 'jira rest api bulk update issue' for more confirmation.